# characteristic polynomial of vector bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

I am trying to understand the following exerpt from [Hitchin - Segal- Ward's book](https://books.google.fr/books?id=eQ8oAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA51&lpg=PA51&dq=Serre%20duality,%20the%20cotangent%20space%20at%20E%20is%20H%5E0&source=bl&ots=85N3Ram6bt&sig=ACfU3U0fCaYg753dAlwafnK5A2za_IqCGw&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiWy9W3vqToAhUqzIUKHW5WBfsQ6AEwAXoECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=Serre%20duality%2C%20the%20cotangent%20space%20at%20E%20is%20H%5E0&f=false) :

A point in the cotangent bundle is thus (up to equivalence) a vector bundle E and a holomorphic section A of $\operatorname{End}E\otimes K$.

> Locally, A is just an $m \times m$ matrix with values in the canonical bundle, and we can take its characteristic polynomial
>   $\operatorname{det}(w - A) = w^m + a_1w^{m-1} + • • • + a_m$ where now instead of each coefficient $a_j$ being a polynomial, it is a global holomorphic section of the line bundle $K^i$.

1. Why is $A$ with values in $K$ and why is $a_i\in K^i$, should I read $a_i \in K^{\otimes i}?$
2. I saw quite few versions of characteristic polynomials (like $\operatorname{det}(\lambda I- A), \operatorname{det}(I_d -A)$) and now $\operatorname{det}(w-A)$. Is there a logic behind these different versions?
3. What is the canonical bundle? (I guess it is the line bundle $K$)?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The canonical bundle is the line bundle $K$ of differential forms of top degree. The characteristic polynomial is the usual one only the notation os bad, $\det(wI-A)$ is what they mean. And yes, $K^i = K^{\otimes i}$.

Comment: Thank you @AlanMuniz for your answer

Comment: @AlanMuniz as the OP notes, that looks like an answer! Would you care to record it below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical bundle is the line bundle (invertible sheaf) $K$ of differential forms of top degree. In this case it is the cotangent bundle of the Riemann Surface. The characteristic polynomial is the usual one only the notation os bad, $\det(wI−A)$ is what they mean. And yes, $K^i=K^{\otimes i}$.

To understand why $A$ is locally a matrix with values in $K$ we only need first to observe that $$(\operatorname{End} E) \otimes K = \operatorname{Hom}(E,E\otimes K)$$to write the morphism $A\colon E \rightarrow E\otimes K$ over a local trivialization. Indeed on a small open set $U$ we may have $E|_U  \simeq U\times \mathbb{C}^m$ and $A$ is given by a $m\times m$ matrix whose entries are  local sections of $K$ i.e. one-forms.

Comment: Could you please correct me if I am wrong: Trivialisation of $\pi:=A : E \to E\otimes K$ would give an homeomorphism $\pi^{-1}(U) \to U \subset  E\otimes K$? and $A$ looks like a projection on $U$, but then the values are still in $E\otimes K$?Then could you please tell why you write $A: E \to E\otimes K$ while $A\in End(E)\otimes K$.Thank you again.

Comment: I expanded a bit the explanation. Tell me if it is clearer.

Comment: Thank you very much, I see now why $A: E \to E\otimes K$. After trivialization, We can write the morphism: $E|_U  \simeq U\times \mathbb{C}^m \to (U\times \mathbb{C}^m) \otimes K$. I still don't get why A would have entries in K, it must be obvious but I don't see it

Comment: $A$ must be a matrix that takes a vector $v$ of holomorphic functions (describing locally a section of $E$) and gives a vector $Av$ of differential forms. Then The entries of $A$ must be differential forms

Comment: I see now! it's cristal clear. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: You're welcome :)